# magento multiple website working with https only

Tags: magento, ssl

I got multiple websites under one magento with domain domain1 and domain2

My base domain is domain1 which is using SSL, I made made second website in same magento by name domain2 without any SSL.

My base domain is working perfectly fine.

Now if i open my second domain with HTTP it goes to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
But works perfectly fine with HTTPS.

Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Are both domains on same IP ?

Comment: yes both are on same IP

Comment: You may want to tag this post with your web server or cross post in Server Fault. It sounds like it could be related to your server configuration.

Comment: server is working all fine. my other websites are working all right